# sqlite3 table_info for a view. what table does the column come from?

Tags: view, sqlite, schema

When I run:

```
PRAGMA table_info(myView)
```

It gives me a list, similar to:

```
0|cardSet|CHAR(255)|0||0
1|multiverseId|INTEGER|0||0
2|cardSetId|INTEGER|0||0
3|name|CHAR(255)|0||0
4|type|CHAR(16)|0||0
5|cost|nvarchar(16)|0||0
6|color|nvarchar(16)|0||0
7|rarity|nvarchar(16)|0||0
```

But from this I have no details on what table those columns are actually in. I was thinking of using a regular expression to try and figure this out, but was wondering if anyone knew of an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to have columns that originate from multiple tables, or from no table at all:

```sql
CREATE VIEW example AS
SELECT a.a1, b.b1, a.a2 + b.b2 AS both, 42 AS neither FROM a, b;
```

In any case, SQLite does not store this information so that it can be accessed directly.
All you can read is the original view definition:

```sql
SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'view' AND name = 'myView'
```